# How to get app name from package Name in android?

Tags: android

I am developing an app in which if any new app is going install in device I have to get app name from package name of that app when app is properly installed for this I am doing that below code. but it always show (unknown) message to me not app name.Please help me.

here is my code:-

```
    public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public Context context;
    public String title;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Get application status(Install/ Uninstall)
        @SuppressWarnings("UnusedAssignment") boolean applicationStatus = intent.getBooleanExtra(Intent.EXTRA_REPLACING, false);
        String toastMessage = null;

        // Check if the application is install or uninstall and display the message accordingly
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED")) {
            // Application Install
            toastMessage = "PACKAGE_INSTALL: " + intent.getData().toString() + getApplicationName(context, intent.getData().toString());
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED")) {

            // Application Uninstall
            toastMessage = "PACKAGE_REMOVED: " + intent.getData().toString() + getApplicationName(context, intent.getData().toString());
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED")) {
            // Application Replaced
            toastMessage = "PACKAGE_REPLACED: " + intent.getData().toString() + getApplicationName(context, intent.getData().toString());
        }

        //Display Toast Message
        if (toastMessage != null) {
            Toast.makeText(context, toastMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        System.out.println("App Name:" + title);
    }

    /**
     * This method get application name name from application package name
     */
    private String getApplicationName(Context context, String data) {

        final PackageManager pckManager = context.getPackageManager();
        ApplicationInfo applicationInformation;
        try {
            applicationInformation = pckManager.getApplicationInfo(data, 0);
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            applicationInformation = null;
        }

        title = (String) (applicationInformation != null ? pckManager.getApplicationLabel(applicationInformation) : "(unknown)");
        return title;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to use [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html)

```
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;

PackageManager pkManager = getPackageManager();
        ApplicationInfo appInfo;
        String packageName=getApplicationContext().getApplicationInfo().packageName;
        try {
            appInfo = pkManager.getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0);
            final String appname = (String)((appInfo != null) ? pkManager.getApplicationLabel(appInfo) : "???");
                    Log.e("appname", appname);
        } catch (final NameNotFoundException e) {}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't get the package info after it is removed.